# Is there something similar to java tag library in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anything similar to java tag library in rails? Thus, you can put the (standard or customer) tag in .html.erb file and the tag will translated into html automatically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would be its advantage over standard templating formats?

Comment: I think you can reuse many pieces of code if you have a customized tag library

Comment: So you can using partials and/or helpers and/or draper presenters.. If I understand JSTL well, it's there to eliminate larger chunks of Java in your presentation code.